# Is it possible to roll over a log fie, without creating a backup?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I would like to create a rolling metrics log file, where metrics data its written to it every few minutes. As a result, the file will get big very fast, but the actually relevant information in it, is just a small 1-hour time window. I want no backups of it.

Using log4j, is there a way to create a rolling appender, without creating backup files every hour?

Answer (score 0):

From docs [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html) you can set MaxBackupIndex is equal to zero

```
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=0


 rollOver

public void rollOver()

    Implements the usual roll over behaviour.

    If MaxBackupIndex is positive, then files {File.1, ..., File.MaxBackupIndex -1} are renamed to {File.2, ..., File.MaxBackupIndex}. Moreover, File is renamed File.1 and closed. A new File is created to receive further log output.

    If MaxBackupIndex is equal to zero, then the File is truncated with no backup files created.
```